# New footer trims horizon

Tags: bug, status-planned, design

I was looking at the footer of any page, it's a bit cut off on the top - seems like we could use a little more padding on the bottom so that where it fades to white is more aligned with where the background is actually white.

I'm running Firefox 54 if that makes any difference.

[image]

Comment: It's likely because of new footer we've just launched. Could you provide some screenshots showing what you're thinking about (it's hard to visualize it for me)?

Comment: I don't remember what it looked like before, but when I look at it while logged out, the sky is visible at the top of the header, below the white background.  Logged in I see no sky in Chrome.

Comment: @Paweł there ya go, bumping the padding of the footer "-container" div up from 32 to 52 fixes it pretty good.

Comment: @Paweł The old footer was much taller and the background appears to be anchored to the bottom of the page. The old footer gave enough room that the picture naturally provided a transition from the footer area into the page area. The current size awkwardly places the footer at almost exactly the horizon making for an ugly color transition, a poorly frames the content. Just slide down the background attachment point so we loose some of the field but get some of the sky back.

Comment: Whoopee! I've been using the site for my entire professional career and finally posted a real bug report.